# Use viewLifecycleOwner as the LifecycleOwner

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have a fragment:

```
class MyFragment : BaseFragment() {

   // my StudentsViewModel instance
   lateinit var viewModel: StudentsViewModel

   override fun onCreateView(...){
        ...
   }

   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

       viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(StudentsViewModel::class.java)
       updateStudentList()
   }

   fun updateStudentList() {
        // Compiler error on 'this': Use viewLifecycleOwner as the LifecycleOwner
        viewModel.students.observe(this, Observer {
            //TODO: populate recycler view
        })
    }
}
```

In my fragment, I have a instance of StudentsViewModel which is initiated in `onViewCreated(...)`.

In, `StudentsViewModel`, `students` is a `LiveData`:

```
class StudentsViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val students = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
          ...
    }
}
```

Back to `MyFragment`, in function `updateStudentList()` I get compiler error complaining the `this` parameter I passed in to `.observe(this, Observer{...})` that `Use viewLifecycleOwner as the LifecycleOwner`

Why I get this error? How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

> Why I get this error?

Lint is recommending that you use the lifecycle of the fragment's views (`viewLifecycleOwner`) rather than the lifecycle of the fragment itself (`this`). Ian Lake and Jeremy Woods of Google go over the difference as part of [this Android Developer Summit presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RS1IACnZLy4), and Ibrahim Yilmaz covers the differences in [this Medium post](https://medium.com/@cs.ibrahimyilmaz/viewlifecycleowner-vs-this-a8259800367b) In a nutshell:

- `viewLifecycleOwner` is tied to when the fragment has (and loses) its UI (`onCreateView()`, `onDestroyView()`)
- `this` is tied to the fragment's overall lifecycle (`onCreate()`, `onDestroy()`), which may be substantially longer

> How to get rid of it?

Replace:

```
viewModel.students.observe(this, Observer {
        //TODO: populate recycler view
    })
```

with:

```
viewModel.students.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        //TODO: populate recycler view
    })
```

In your current code, if `onDestroyView()` is called, but `onDestroy()` is not, you will continue observing the `LiveData`, perhaps crashing when you try populating a non-existent `RecyclerView`. By using `viewLifecycleOwner`, you avoid that risk.

Comment: Note that you should still use "this" in case of DialogFragment (and probably every fragment that doesn't return a view for onCreateView. Otherwise you will get an exception: `IllegalStateException: Can't access the Fragment View's LifecycleOwner when getView() is null i.e., before onCreateView() or after onDestroyView()`

Comment: @androiddeveloper You could still use lifeCycleOwner in onViewCreated and onwards?

Comment: @jontro Pretty sure you can. Try it and let me know :)

Comment: You'll get an exception if you try accessing viewLifecycleOwner in a DialogFragment on which you create your own dialog (overriding onCreateDialog instead of onCreateView)

Comment: Crash will not happen because livedata doesn't notify observers if a fragment in STOP state.

Comment: @LeonWu: "Crash will not happen because livedata doesn't notify observers if a fragment in STOP state" -- again, there are two lifecycles for fragments, not one. Google repeatedly has told us to tie fragment UI concerns to `viewLifecycleOwner`.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, but the key issue is livedata may be observed multiple times. I only against adding view could crash.

Comment: viewLifecycleOwner will not work if not inside onviewCreated

Answer (score 14):

viewLifeCycleOwner is LifecycleOwner that represents the Fragment's View lifecycle. In most cases, this mirrors the lifecycle of the Fragment itself, but in cases of detached Fragments, the lifecycle of the Fragment can be considerably longer than the lifecycle of the View itself.

Fragment views get destroyed when a user navigates away from a fragment, even though the fragment itself is not destroyed. This essentially creates two lifecycles, the lifecycle of the fragment, and the lifecycle of the fragment's view. Referring to the fragment's lifecycle instead of the fragment view's lifecycle can cause subtle bugs when updating the fragment's view.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `this` use `viewLifecycleOwner` to observe `LiveData`

```
viewModel.students.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    //TODO: populate recycler view
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Captain obvious here, also useful could be this:

```
viewModel.searchConfiguration.observe(requireParentFragment().viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {}
```