# Can't observe correctly: viewLifecycleOwner vs this

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-architecture-navigation, android-mvvm

Let's imagine the following case: we have BottomNavigationView with Navigation Component and MVVM architecture.

In which case in Fragment this line of code will now work

**onViewCreated()**

```kotlin
viewModel.isActionDone.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    doReaction()
}
```

but this code will?

```kotlin
private val observer = Observer<Boolean> {
    doReaction()
}
```

**onViewCreated()**

```kotlin
viewModel.isActionDone.observe(this, observer)
```

In my app, the second code works great, but the first code doesn`t work correctly: when I move to another element in the BottomNavigationView, the observer is called several times.

P.S. this code also calling observer several times.

```kotlin
viewModel.isActionDone.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, observer)
```

Сould you please help me understand what could be wrong with the first code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59521691/use-viewlifecycleowner-as-the-lifecycleowner

Comment: @ADM, I know that I should use **viewLifecycleOwner**, but I still can't understand why using **this** does not bring multiple calls, and **viewLifecycleOwner** brings

Answer (score 0):

it's because every time `onStart()` is called on your fragment, the livedata becomes active again and emits the last value again. you should use the `Event` class as a wrapper or you could use the `SingleLiveEvent` class which is now considered an anti pattern.
you could read this for more information: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150

Comment: `it's because every time onStart() is called on your fragment, the livedata becomes active again and emits the last value again` it's not true

Comment: @IR42 yes it is true

Comment: SingleLiveEvent has been an official anti-pattern since about 2018

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yeah, I wasn't a developer back then :D

Answer (score 0):

It's because When you move to another fragment, NavController destroy the view and stop the fragment and when you back to the first fragment, fragment will be started and view will be created again.

So when you're using "viewLifecycleOwner" for observe, your LiveData emit the last value each time when you back to the first fragment. but when using "this", it does not.

So you should think about your business that you need have emits each time your view created or each time fragment created and use suitable LifecycleOwner.

I home it help you.